# Using sum() in a list

Tags: python, list, grok

I'm a bit new to coding and I have a school project where we have to make a code using python, in the code we get an input from the user and need to add it together in a list, this is the code:

```
x = input("Enter the expenses: ")
y = x.split()
n = sum(y)
print("Total: $"+ n +"")
```

I have looked all over the internet and apparently this is correct but for some reason I always get an error saying:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "program.py", line 3, in <module>
    n = sum(y)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to convert your string values to `int`.

Comment: try adding `str(n)` to the print string

Comment: @PatrickParker this code fails before `n` is even assigned.

Comment: right, because y contains strings you need to map them to int

Answer (score 0):

The elements of y are strings so you can't sum it up. Change then to ints first like:

`y = list(map(int, y))`

and then do the sum

Comment: Note: If you don't otherwise need the values, you can omit the `list()` wrapping; `map` itself returns an iterator that `sum` can consume, it'll just be exhausted by `sum`. `list`'ll let you store all the values and reuse them.

Comment: It says that 'Y is not defined'

Comment: Your variable is lower case y

Comment: my bad, it says 'y is not defined'

Comment: Are you running it after this line: `y = x.split()`